# good practice regarding declaring variables inside a loop that we know will be run through

Tags: python, pep

Here, PyCharm warns me for using b outside of the while loop because, and I agree, if we don't go through the loop, `b` will not be defined.

[image]

What is the best practice here, adding `# noqa` after `b["test"] = 8`, declaring `b = {}` before the while loop (but then we are re-declaring it to be `b = {}` the first time we go through the loop)? I'd tend to the second solution because it makes the code more readable, but maybe there's a better solution?

Code:

```py
a = 0
while a != 10:
    b = {}
    a += 1
    b[a] = "something"
b["test"] = 8
```

Comment: My minimal reproducible example was indeed not the most relevant, I've updated it to be in a way that re-declaring it `b` each time is necessary. Sorry.

Comment: It's still not really obvious why re-defining `b` inside the loop is necessary, but regardless, you would do both - define `b` before the loop, and again in the loop. Rule of thumb: If I need `b` to exist after the loop, regardless of whether or not the loop runs, then I should define it before the loop.

Comment: Ok! So, the conclusion I gathered is: it's not bad practice to define `b` before even though we know it will be declared twice.

Comment: There are no declarations in python. Only definition. You define `b` outside the loop to prevent an error if the loop isn't entered. You re-define `b` inside the loop with whatever value you want it to have. Note that in your case you only really define the value of the dict at the key `a`, i.e. `b[a]` in the loop. If you _re-define `b` to be an empty dict in every iteration of the loop_, it will have only one key -- the one you set in the last iteration -- when your loop ends. In other words, your code is not the same as simply moving the definition of `b`outside the loop (run it and see why)

Comment: No yes I get that, my code doesn't make sense because it's a minimal reproducible example. My question was: is it bad practice to do b = {} and then inside the loop b = {} because I want to "reset" b at each iteration of the loop. and use b after the loop. Even though I KNOW for a fact the loop will be run through at least once.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that is an example code but it has no sense to redeclare `b` each time. The best solution is to declare it before the `while` (it's a mandatory practice in languages as C/C++). So, the code will be:

```
a = 0    
b = {}
while a != 10:
    a += 1
    b["something"] = a
b["test"] = 8
```

Comment: My minimal reproducible example was indeed not the most relevant, I've updated it to be in a way that re-declaring it `b` each time is necessary. My bad.

Comment: Ok, in such a case the best practice would be declaring `b` as if the execution doesn't enter to the `while`. That is, you have to question yourself what is the default value of `b` in the case of `not a != 10`?

Comment: Ok thank you! The conclusion I gathered is: it's not bad practice to define `b` before even though we know it will be declared twice.